# How to autoplay a html5video on a mobile

Tags: html, video

Below is the code for a video I am wanting to play automatically on a mobile device. It autostart on the desktop but not when the page is loaded on an iPhone.

```
<div class="w3-row">
<div class="w3-col w3-full">
<div class="w3-display-container" >


        <div id="videoWrapper_disable">
        <!-- Start EasyHtml5Video.com BODY section -->


        <div class="easyhtml5video" style="position:relative;max-width:1280px;">

        <video playsinline controls="controls"  autoplay="autoplay" poster="w3movies/Forever_I_Run_%28Live%29_-_Elevation_Worship.jpg" style="width:100%"  loop="loop" onended="var v=this;setTimeout(function(){v.play()},1)">

        <source playsinline src="w3movies/Forever_I_Run_%28Live%29_-_Elevation_Worship.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
        <source playsinline src="w3movies/Forever_I_Run_%28Live%29_-_Elevation_Worship.mp4" />

        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="w3movies/flashfox.swf" width="1280" height="720" style="position:relative;">
        <param name="movie" value="w3movies/flashfox.swf" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
        <param name="flashVars" value="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;fullScreenEnabled=false&amp;posterOnEnd=true&amp;loop=true&amp;poster=w3movies/Forever_I_Run_%28Live%29_-_Elevation_Worship.jpg&amp;src=Forever_I_Run_%2528Live%2529_-_Elevation_Worship.m4v" />
        <embed src="w3movies/flashfox.swf" width="1280" height="720" style="position:relative;"  flashVars="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;fullScreenEnabled=false&amp;posterOnEnd=true&amp;loop=true&amp;poster=w3movies/Forever_I_Run_%28Live%29_-_Elevation_Worship.jpg&amp;src=Forever_I_Run_%2528Live%2529_-_Elevation_Worship.m4v"   allowFullScreen="false" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer_en" />
        <img alt="Forever I Run (Live) - Elevation Worship" src="w3movies/Forever_I_Run_%28Live%29_-_Elevation_Worship.jpg" style="position:absolute;left:0;" width="100%" title="Video playback is not supported by your browser" />
        </object>

        </video>

        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="w3movies/html5ext.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has disabled autoplay on mobile safari for videos with sound. You must start with the sound muted, or wait for the user to click the play button.